# open-uri Ruby Errors

Tags: ruby

I have the code:

```
require 'open-uri'
print "Enter a URL: "
add = gets
added = add.sub!(/http:\/\//, "")
puts "Info from:  #{add}"
open("#{add}") do |f|
  img = f.read.scan(/<img/)
  img = img.length
  puts "\t#{img} images"
  f.close
end
open("#{add}") do |f|
  links = f.read.scan(/<a/)
  links = links.length
  puts "\t#{links} links"
  f.close
end
open("#{add}") do |f|
  div = f.read.scan(/<div/)
  div = div.le1ngth
  puts "\t#{div} div tags"
  f.close
end
```

(Yes I know it isn't good code, don't comment about it please)
When I run it, and for the URL, I enter in, say:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in `initialize': No such file or directory - http (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in `open_uri_original_open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in `open'
```

Why does this error come up and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.sub!` method replaces the string in place, so `add.sub!(/http:\/\//, "")` changes the value of `add` in addition to setting `added`.

To use the `open(name)` method with URIs, the value of `name` must start with a URI scheme, like `http://`.

If you want to set `added`, do so like so:

```
added = add.sub(/http:\/\//, "")
```